# How to decrease number by 1 and when it hits 0 goes back to the starting point?

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I have an array with a length of 3 so indexes 0,1,and 2. Then I have a counter(int c) and a rollover limit(int rollover = array.length) and two buttons that listen for when they are click will determine to go ahead one or go back one.

```
prev.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(c!=0) {
                c--;
                updateLabel(pokemons[c]);
            } else if(c==0) {
                c = rollover;
                updateLabel(pokemons[c]);
            }

        }

    });

    next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            c = (c+1) % rollover; //increase c until the limit
            if(c==rollover) {
                updateLabel(pokemons[c]);
            }
            else if(c<rollover) {
                updateLabel(pokemons[c]);

            }


        }

    });
```

The "next" button works, but my "prev" button encounters an error when you are at index 0, but works again when you click it again. Basically I have a JLabel that shows pictures of pokemon and when I click next or prev it calls the updateLabel method to change the JLabel and shows the next or previous pokemon in the array. Any ideas on how to fix the prev button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be `c = rollover-1;` here:

```
        if(c!=0) {
            c--;
            updateLabel(pokemons[c]);
        } else if(c==0) {
            c = rollover-1; // <-- here
            updateLabel(pokemons[c]);
        }
```

Comment: That's it. `rollover == pokemons.length`. The max index is `pokemons.length - 1`. In fact, this bit of code `if(c==rollover)` in the `next` callback never gets hit. In modular arithmetic, the 0 <= mod(c) < rollover. Also, you could implement `prev` similarly to `next`, doing something like `c = (c-1) % rollover;` The `-1 % rollover` will be equal to `rollover - 1`.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem it went out of bounds